# Why does last popover link in navbar not centre on object?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, popover, navbar

I am using bootstrap.js to build a simple UI. As part of this UI I want to use a navbar.

On the navbar, I would like to have a popover under each of the items in the navbar. This works OK.

What I have noticed, however is that the popover on the last link item in the nav bar does not position correctly.

It does not matter if the last item is the third of three, or the sixth of six, it is only the last item that is affected.

I can workaround this by not using a popover on the last item, however I do not understand *why* this is occurring.

I have tested this in Chrome 28 and Firefox 21 locally with the same results.

**My question is: why does the last popover in the code below cause a strange rendering issue?**

Nice Example (Cursor is hovering over the middle link) :
[image: Cursor is hovering over the middle link]

Yucky Example (Cursor is hovering over the last link):
[image: Rendering not quite right on the popover]

The code I am using to reproduce this behaviour:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD><link href="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"></HEAD>
<BODY>
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#" id="l1" rel="popover">ABCDEFG</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="l2" rel="popover">ABCDEFG</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="l3" rel="popover">ABCDEFG</a></li>      
     </ul>  
  </div>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http:///netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
<script src="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
<script>
$(function ()  
{ 
    var globalDelay = { show: 200, hide: 100 };
    var lcontent = "ABCDEFG ABCDEFG ABCDEFG";
    var ltitle = "ABCDEFG ABCDEFG ABCDEFG";
    $("#l1").popover({placement:'bottom', trigger:'hover', content:lcontent ,title:ltitle, delay:globalDelay}); 
    $("#l2").popover({placement:'bottom', trigger:'hover', content:lcontent ,title:ltitle, delay:globalDelay}); 
    $("#l3").popover({placement:'bottom', trigger:'hover', content:lcontent ,title:ltitle, delay:globalDelay}); 
});  
</script> 
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to relate to the width of the object that contains the list items.

If I make a slight change to the code above (shown below), I can workaround the behaviour.
It appears that the width of the ul object as it is rendered by bootstrap, causes the final popover to be chopped short, which results in the arrow div offset also against the list item in the navbar.

```
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <ul class="nav" style="width:100%;">
      <li><a href="#" id="l1" rel="popover">ABCDEFG</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="l2" rel="popover">ABCDEFG</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="l3" rel="popover">ABCDEFG</a></li>      
     </ul>  
  </div>
</div>
```